# Dynamically build a lambda function in python

Tags: python, scipy

Supose that I want to generate a function to be later incorporated in a set of equations to be solved with scipy nsolve function. I want to create a function like this:

xi + xi+1 + xi+3 = 1

in which the number of variables will be dependent on the number of components. For example, if I have 2 components:

```
 f = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] - 1
```

for 3:

```
 f = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 1
```

I specify the components as an array within the arguments of the function to be called:

```
 def my_func(components):
        for component in components:
        .....
        .....
        return f
```

I can't just find a way of doing this. I've to be able to make it this way as this function and other functions need to be solved together with nsolve:

```
 x0 = scipy.optimize.fsolve(f, [0, 0, 0, 0 ....])
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

---

Since I'm not sure which is the best way of doing this I will fully explain what I'm trying to do:

-I'm trying to generate this two functions to be later nsolved:

[image]

[image]

So I want to create a function teste([list of components]) that can return me this two equations (Psat(T) is a function I can call depending on the component and P is a constant(value = 760)).

Example:

```
  teste(['Benzene','Toluene'])
```

would return:

xBenzene + xToluene = 1

xBenzene*Psat('Benzene') + xToluene*Psat('Toluene') = 760

in the case of calling:

```
   teste(['Benzene','Toluene','Cumene'])
```

it would return:

xBenzene + xToluene + xCumene = 1

xBenzene*Psat('Benzene') + xToluene*Psat('Toluene') + xCumene*Psat('Cumene') = 760

All these x values are not something I can calculate and turn into a list I can sum. They are variables that are created as a function ofthe number of components I have in the system...

Hope this helps to find the best way of doing this

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to do, that makes you think that building a lambda function dynamically is part of the answer, or that switching on the number of components instead of just iterating them is part of the answer? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Also, a lot of people who ask these kinds of questions seem to think there is something special about lambda functions. There is not. There is not even such a thing as a "lambda function". A function is a function, whether defined by `lambda` or `def`.

Comment: Yap, trying to solve a xy value for a specified T in which the equations depend on the number of components I send to the function:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/29352/5/content/html/Antoine_tutorial_eq62913.png
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/29352/5/content/html/Antoine_tutorial_eq52281.png

Comment: (Note: abarnert isn't talking about the same type of XY problem as you.)

Comment: My bad...just finished reading the article know lol

Comment: I suspect there's a much more efficient way than building these functions, but with my limited knowledge of scipy, I can't offer one.

Comment: Oh dear. At least half the answerers have either misunderstood your question or bugged up their code, since the 4 posted answers have 3 different behaviors. If you can improve the phrasing of your question, you may want to do so.

Comment: Yes... edited with fully explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take advantage of numpy and do something like:

```
def teste(molecules):
    P = np.array([Psat(molecule) for molecule in molecules])
    f1 = lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1
    f2 = lambda x: np.dot(x, P) - 760
    return f1, f2
```

Actually what you are trying to solve is a possibly underdetermined system of linear equations, of the form A.x = b. You can construct A and b as follows:

```
A = np.vstack((np.ones((len(molecules),)),
               [Psat(molecule) for molecule in molecules]))
b = np.array([1, 760])
```

And you could then create a single lambda function returning a 2 element vector as:

```
return lambda x: np.dot(A, x) - b
```

But I really don´t think that is the best approach to solving your equations: either you have a single solution you can get with `np.linalg.solve(A, b)`, or you have a linear system with infinitely many solutions, in which case what you want to find is a base of the solution space, not a single point in that space, which is what you will get from a numerical solver that takes a function as input.

Comment: Many thanks Jaime, this is exactly what I was looking for! By the way, as you seem to be a scipy/numpy expert do you know if there is any way of solving a system of non-linear equations with constraints?
Solution of my problem gave me x1= 21 and x2 = -22 when they should be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 7):

A direct translation would be:

```
f = lambda *x: sum(x) - 1
```

But not sure if that's really what you want.

Comment: I think this is exactly what he wants. +1

Comment: That is nice and elegant, i have been thinking about similar problems too and never thought to use *x in lambdas, (or actually never used *args anywhere before, though i get the reason for it)

Comment: This is a great answer; thank you---I ended up using a list comprehension but this looks so much better.

Answer (score 7):

You can dynamically build a lambda with a string then parse it with the eval function like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

s = "lambda x: "
s += " + ".join(["x[" + str(i) + "]" for i in xrange(0, 3)]) # Specify any range
s += " - 1"

print s

f = eval(s)
print f(a)
```

Comment: `eval` can be dangerous: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html. Plus in this case, using `lambda` isn't necessarily the best method.

Comment: eval is only dangerous if you take the string from user input. It is clearly not the case in this application. Jon's answer assume that all elements in x must be summed, which may not be case. I'm merely showing an example of how to dynamically create a lambda that is flexible enough to serve OP.

Comment: This is basically what I want to do...
Just not sure if it is the best way of solving my problem. But works!
Thanks

PS: If possible have a look at my updated question

Comment: Even if it isn't dangerous it is greatly unnecessary to have that intermediate string, not to speak about beauty, elegance and readability (or lack of it). Plus having the length of the input hardcoded means it hardly qualifies as dynamically building the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to define a function by building it up iteratively, you can. I can't think of  any situation where this would be the best answer, or even a reasonable one, but it's what you asked for, so:

```
def my_func(components):
    f = lambda x: -1
    for component in components:
        def wrap(f):
            return lambda x: component * x[0] + f(x[1:])
        f = wrap(f)
    return f
```

Now:

```
>>> f = my_func([1, 2, 3])
>>> f([4,5,6])
44
```

Of course this will be no fun to debug. For example, look at the traceback from calling `f([4,5])`.

Answer (score -3):

```
def make_constraint_function(components):
    def constraint(vector):
        return sum(vector[component] for component in components) - 1
    return constraint
```

You could do it with a lambda, but a named function may be more readable. `def`fed functions can do anything lambdas can and more. Make sure to give the function a good docstring, and use variable and function names appropriate for your program.